# How to search some data with foreign key?

Tags: database, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-9

On my site I've some ads. I'm trying to filter/search ads using a foreign key.
On my ad I have some values, for example 'names' or 'city_id'.
City_id is my foreign key for all the French cities.

In my example I want to search ads that contain "Le mans" for city.
Le mans is id = 1.

So when a user writes "Le mans" I need to find the id in the City table, and ads where city_id is this id.

```
public $query ='';
public $annonces = [];

public function updatedQuery()
{
    $words = '%' . $this->query . '%'; 
    if (strlen($this->query) > 1) {
    
    $city = City::select('id')->where('city_name', 'like', $words)->get();
    
    $this->annonces = Annonce::where('name', 'like', $words)
    ->orWhere('city_id', 'like', $city)->get(); 
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: Please do not change your question after a reasonable answer. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Your question is not a place to ask about an answer, comment on it or post a new question about it. Give credit for other people's code/writing & say you are quoting & format as a quote. If you don't know whether something works it shouldn't be in a post. You don't even relate it to the rest of your post. I rolled it back. [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public $query ='';
public $annonces = [];

public function updatedQuery()
{
    $words = '%' . $this->query . '%'; 
    if (strlen($this->query) > 1) {
    
    $cities = City::where('city_name', 'like', $words)->get(['id']); //get() method returns Collection
    
    foreach($cities as $city) {
    $this->annonces = Annonce::where('name', 'like', $words)
    ->orWhere('city_id', 'like', $city)->get(); 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i tried it and it doesn't worked. I use another way. I'm curious to have your point on it. I add it to my initial question.